# Make a part of List item a different color and not the entire list item?

Tags: asp.net

I have a listbox item like "I understand and agree .....". In order to notify users, I have a requirement to add a text in front of that item before "I understand" with a text called "New:" with Green colour so that users understand that it is a new statement in the listbox. What I did makes entire list item green, Can I just make a single text colour green in the list item and not the entire list item?

```
  <asp:ListItem Value="4" onclick="CheckAllConditions();" style="color:green"> New:  I understand and agree the statement!  </asp:ListItem>
```

I just need the text "New:" as Green colour. How to do this?Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:ListItem Value="4" onclick="CheckAllConditions();"> 
    <span style="color:green;">New:</span>  
    I understand and agree the statement!  
</asp:ListItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Joel Coehoorn's answer is incorrect. You cannot put a `<span>` element inside a `ListItem` for a ListBox control.

The listbox control in ASP.Net is rendered as a `<select>` element in the browser, where every `ListItem` is converted into an `<option>` element. It is possible to an entire `<option>` element, but you can't style parts of it separately.

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option), the option element only allows plain text inside it (i.e. other elements such as `<span>` are not allowed).

> **Permitted content**:    Text, possibly with escaped characters (like `&eacute;`).

Here's an example where I have put in the markup to style the text inside an `<option>` element. You'll notice that the entire second option is green, while no part of the third item is green.

```html
<select multiple>
  <option>Some text</option>
  <option style="color: green;">Green text</option>
  <option><span style="color: green">Green text</span> - Normal Text</option>
</select>
```

---

You can however use a pseudo element to insert the content "New" before an option and give it green color.

In the snippet below I have applied CSS Class `new-item` to one of the options, and added the content "New" with green color to the `::before` pseudo element using it.

```css
.new-item::before {
  content: "New: ";
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<select multiple>
  <option>Some text</option>
  <option style="color: green;">Green text</option>
  <option class="new-item">
    I understant...
  </option>
</select>
```

The markup in ASP.Net should be:

```
<asp:ListItem Value="4" onclick="CheckAllConditions();" CssClass="new-item"> 
    I understand and agree the statement!  
</asp:ListItem>
```